# Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function htmlout() in

Tags: php, pdo

Debo mostrar una consulta en una tabla y me sale el siguiente error:

> Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function htmlout() in C:\xampp\htdocs\proyectos\codigo_barras\showcdb\show.html.php:40 Stack trace: #0 C:\xampp\htdocs\proyectos\codigo_barras\showcdb\index.php(70): include() #1 {main} thrown in C:\xampp\htdocs\proyectos\codigo_barras\showcdb\show.html.php on line 40

Adjunto el código del **`show.html.php`**:

```
<tbody>
  <?php foreach ($codibarres as $barres): ?>
    <tr>
      <td><?php htmlout($barres['id_barra']); ?></td>
      <td><?php htmlout($barres['id_barra']); ?></td>
      <td><?php htmlout($barres['id_barra']); ?></td>
      <td><?php htmlout($barres['id_barra']); ?></td>
      <td><?php htmlout($barres['id_barra']); ?></td>
    </tr>
    <?php endforeach; ?>
</tbody>
```

Y en el índice tengo esto cabe destacar que la conexión a la base de datos la realiza correctamente

```
foreach($dades as $barres){
    $codibarres[] = array('id_barra' => $barres['id_barra'],
    'ALTO' => $barres['ALTO'], 'ANCHO' => $barres['ANCHO'],
    'PROFUNDIDAD' => $barres['PROFUNDIDAD'], 'PESO'  => $barres['PESO']);
}

session_start();
```

Comment: ¿Dónde declaras o tratas de usar la función `htmlout()`?

Comment: Al final lo solucioné con un echo

Comment: Pero un echo de que?

Comment: donde ponía el htmlout puse el echo($barres['id_barra']); y funcionó

Comment: Al margen de que eso no esta en tu pregunta, considera editarla y agregar detalles relevantes así como publicar tu solución